# Postgres Group By - Ratio Calculation per User

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a table of bets and one column called 'Status' which indicates if it is 'Correct' or 'Incorrect'. I can compute the ratio for an specific user as:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet WHERE user_id = 1 AND status = 'Correct')::DECIMAL AS correct_guesses,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet WHERE user_id = 1 AND status = 'Incorrect')::DECIMAL AS incorrect_guesses,
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet WHERE user_id = 1 AND status = 'Correct') AS DECIMAL) / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet WHERE user_id = 1 AND status = 'Incorrect') AS DECIMAL) AS Ratio;
```

But if I try to do it grouping by user it computes the same value for all of them.

```
SELECT
    user_id, accounts_usuario.username, 
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM bets_bet WHERE status = 'Correct') AS Corrects,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM bets_bet WHERE status = 'Incorrect') AS Incorrects,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM bets_bet WHERE status = 'Pending') AS Pending,
    --CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL) / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet) AS DECIMAL) AS Ratio
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet WHERE status = 'Correct') AS DECIMAL) / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet WHERE status = 'Incorrect') AS DECIMAL) AS Ratio
FROM bets_bet
LEFT JOIN accounts_usuario ON bets_bet.user_id = accounts_usuario.id
GROUP BY user_id, accounts_usuario.username
ORDER BY Ratio, Corrects;
```

[image]

How could I achieve the desired output?

#### Update

I am facing the same problem after implementing next logic:

I have created the class SeasonalUser to store the bets of each year, and the field user is a Foreign Key to the id of the User class. So now I have the same logic but with 3 tables and I am getting again the same value for every field.

```
-- Calculate the accuracy ratio for every SeasonUser
SELECT
    bet.user_id, usr.username, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  status = 'Correct'   THEN  1 END) AS Corrects, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  status = 'Incorrect' THEN  1 END) AS Incorrects, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  status = 'Pending'   THEN  1 END) AS Pending,    

    CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN  status = 'Correct' THEN  1 END) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Incorrect' THEN 1 END) AS DECIMAL) AS Ratio

FROM bets_bet AS bet
LEFT JOIN accounts_seasonusuario AS s_usr ON bet.user_id = s_usr.id
LEFT JOIN accounts_usuario AS usr ON usr.id = s_usr.user_id
GROUP BY bet.user_id, s_usr.id, usr.username
ORDER BY Ratio DESC, Corrects DESC;
```

I don't really want to group by usr.username (the User global) because I want the ratio per year, but it looks like it is mandatory if I want to print the real username in the returning table `usr.username`.

What am I missing?

Comment: lets say bets_bet t2 for sub query and bets_bet t1 for main query. Add condition t1.user_id = t2.user_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL 1:

```
SELECT
    user_id, accounts_usuario.username, 
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM bets_bet t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id and status = 'Correct') AS Corrects,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM bets_bet t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id and status = 'Incorrect') AS Incorrects,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM bets_bet t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id and  status = 'Pending') AS Pending,
    --CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL) / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet) AS DECIMAL) AS Ratio
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id and  status = 'Correct') AS DECIMAL) / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id and  status = 'Incorrect') AS DECIMAL) AS Ratio
FROM bets_bet t1 
LEFT JOIN accounts_usuario ON bets_bet.user_id = accounts_usuario.id
GROUP BY user_id, accounts_usuario.username
ORDER BY Ratio, Corrects;
```

It will return the same result for all the row because you are not specifying for which user id result should generate. In order to that add condition as shown above.

SQL 2:

```
SELECT
    user_id, accounts_usuario.username, 
    count(case when  status = 'Correct' then  1 end ), 
    count(case when  status = 'Incorrect' then  1 end ), 
    count(case when  status = 'Pending' then  1 end ),    
    --CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL) / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bets_bet) AS DECIMAL) AS Ratio
    count(case when  status = 'Correct' then  1 end ) / count(case when  status = 'Incorrect' then  1 end ) AS Ratio
FROM bets_bet t1 
LEFT JOIN accounts_usuario ON bets_bet.user_id = accounts_usuario.id
GROUP BY user_id, accounts_usuario.username
ORDER BY Ratio, Corrects;
```

You can simply count status as shown in query.

Comment: Thanks! It was just missing the CAST statements right? So the ratio is not 0 after the division

Comment: If you feel cast is required then you can add it.

Comment: Could you see what is wrong with the update? Just adding a third table but the same exact logic that was working for two

Comment: if you want data by year then add year column in group by as well.